# Redefinition of ... Errors in RCTLog.h after linking RNVectorIcons in a React Native project

Tags: xcode, react-native

After running the command `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` I now get a bunch of `Redefintion of ...` errors in RCTLog.h in RNVectorIcons (it has a little column house icon, is that a library?) errors in Xcode in my react native project.  How do I fix these build errors - I tried `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons` but that errors `ERR! It seems something went wrong while unlinking. Error: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined` so it looks like I have to fix this manually.

[image]

For context I was trying to work around the font not found errors from using @shoutem/ui with react native.

https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/95

Comment: Any fixe for this ? Kindly check my post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488993/reactnative-0-59-8-project-unable-to-archive-for-for-ios-while-app-store-relea

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this response to an issue in github https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/134

Looks like the link command for shoutem/ui and vector icons was not updated for react 0.40.  You have to manually change the import statements in the libraries for BVLinearGradient... from

```
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import "RCTView.h"
```

to this

```
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import <React/RCTView.h>
```